# Cakephp 4, What is the best way to deal with many models that depend on each other?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I will try to be brief with the explanation.

I have a model (Orders) that saves data from a huge form.
With these data saved, another model (Quotes) calculates all the items that has to include in order to get the prices, but to make this calculation I have to consult other models.

An unreal example to understand:

OrdersController get request:

```
$orders = [
    'client_id' => '987',
    
    'cpu_type' => 'AMD',
    'cpu_speed' => '> 4 Ghz.',
    'cpu_cores' => '> 6',
    
    'motherboard_ram_sockets' => '4',
    'motherboard_pci_e' => '> 3',
    'motherboard_sata' => 'yes',
    
    'keyboard_wired' => 'yes',
    'keyboard_color' => 'black',
    'keyboard_lang' => 'en',
    
    'ssd_capacity' => '> 512Gb'
    'ssd_type' => 'M.2'
    'ssd_speed' => 'Super Fast',
    'ssd_qty' => '2',
    
    'ram_capacity' => '> 8Gb'
    'ram_type' => 'DDR4'
    'ram_speed' => '> 2666 Mhz',
    'ram_qty' => '4'];
```

I save the data in my Orders table and have to calculate which are the items that match the requirements.

My other tables are like:

### products

| id | code | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | INTL123 | CPU Intel 4Ghz 5 Cores | $456 |
| 84 | AMD567 | Cpu AMD 2.5Ghz 3 Cores | $64 |
| 125 | Mem54 | Ram Module 8Gb DDR4 | $79 |
| 185 | Kbrd | Keybord Wired Black | $33 |

### cpus

| id | product_id | cpu_type | cpu_speed | cpu_cores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | Intel | 4Ghz | 5 |
| 2 | 84 | AMD | 2.5Ghz | 3 |

### rams

| id | product_id | ram_type | ram_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 125 | DDR4 | 2666 |

Several tables later ...

### quotes

| id | order_id | product_id | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 | 25 | 1 |
| 2 | 456 | 84 | 3 |
| 3 | 456 | 125 | 4 |
| 4 | 456 | 185 | 1 |

Finally, my question is ...

What is the best way to get this data?
Triggering an "Order Created" event?
Instantiating all necessary models and running functions?
Is there a better way to do this, for example saving the characteristics of each product in a single table?
I would like to do it in the most decoupled way possible to be able to add more items in the future and not have to change the logic.

Comment: Your posted data is lookig for a 6 core 4GHz AMD CPU, but your CPUs table doesn't have that. What does it do in such a case?

Comment: Throw an exception. Anyway, it is not the important thing. The data that I put is as an example. What interests me to know is how I should proceed with logic.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is not how to handle data in this format, but rather that your data is coming in the wrong format. Why do you let people select CPU type, speed and core separately in your form if that's likely to result in unworkable combinations? Seems more standard to present them with a list of actual options from the cpus table (perhaps with nice JS filtering), and then what you get is a very manageable list of product IDs to link to your quote.

Comment: I thank you for the responses. But, I insist, the data I show is an example to make it easier to understand. My app is about Quotations for Elevators controller system. The options selected by the user (type of Motor, power, maneuver, number of stops, types of doors, etc) determine the components that the controller must have. Believe me, there are thousands of possible combinations. The seller does not know the components that he has to carry, but the general characteristics for their application. For this reason, the quote is indirect and I cannot select the components one by one.

Comment: Analogies very often lose the essence of the problem. Any chance that you can rewrite your question to use actual details? Might be more likely to get a useful answer that way.